# Is sending binary data faster than plain text?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, binary-data

I've always been sending data from frontend to backend via POST method as a JSON array - and decoding that JSON on the server side. It works, it's fast, everybody does that.

But there's a different approach - converting JSON array into bytes stream using buffer array on the server side, sending it as octet-stream to the server using the following pattern:

```
length_of_next_block_data(int32) byte byte byte byte length_of_next_block_data(int32) byte byte byte byte byte byte
```

And writing a decoder on the server receiving this - with int32 separators saying how long the block of data would be it should be easy to use in each situation.

I've heard that google uses a similat approach. Is this faster? Is this worth doing?

Comment: why not base64 as well or instead?

Comment: "faster" being 0.01 sec instead of 0.02 sec?  And is encoding + transmission + decoding really going to be faster than just sending plain json?  All I see here is something that will be harder to debug and difficult for 3rd parties to interact with.